# Unbalance current in capacitor bank

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, high-voltage

I'm working with a 11 kV capacitor bank and is trying to calculate (by hand) the I0 current (down right on attached image).
The circuit is three phase, 11 kV ph-ph. The I0-amperemeter is the only amperemeter present in the real circuit, but is only used for protection of the bank. (Disconnect if I0 > xxA) The other amperemeters are added for simulation only.

In a balanced capacitor bank, the I0-current is zero, but I would like to calculate the current based on measurements of the capacitors.

Simulations gave I0=0.2467 A for the conditions shown.

How can I calculate the I0-current, when knowing the voltages (11 kV), and the value of the 6 capacitors?

[image: Curcuit]

Comment: A simulator like LTSpice would eat this problem.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to find an equation to be used for quick check of the I0 current.
Just insert 11 kV, the values of C0-C6 and get the (peak)value of I0...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the simulator to **empirically** derive the equation you are looking for.
Start with all caps the same value, vary the value of one cap pair, and obtaining the corresponding Io.
I believe that the current will be proportional to the "mismatch" between the two caps (per phase), so you will be able to determine the **constant of proportionality (k)** and thereby get your equation (Io = kC).  Also, I believe the **vector** addition of the 3 phases will give you the total Io.